# Unable to Set Content-Description in Mime Header in Python

Tags: python, mime-mail

I am sending multiple file attachments in a mail using python mime library. I am trying to set some values 'Content-Description' field using add_header function, but I am unable to set it.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.compat32-message.html#email.message.Message.add_header

###### Code Snippet

```
msg.add_header('Content-Type','text/html')

msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename="intrusion.html")

msg.add_header`('Content-`Description','This is an Mail Attachment')
```

Kindly advise how headers can be added.

Comment: Can you share your code, please? Even if it doesn't quite work, showing your working will be useful!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers are set automatically by [EmailMessage.add_attachment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.add_attachment).  Additional headers, such as Content-Description, can be passed as a list of colon-separated "header-name:content" strings using the `headers` keyword argument. See the docs for [ContentManager.set_content](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.contentmanager.html#email.contentmanager.set_content), which is called by `add_attachment`.

This example code:

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage    
    
# Create the container email message.    
msg['Subject'] = 'This message has an attachment'     
msg['From'] = 'me@example.com'    
msg['To'] = 'you@example.com'    
    
msg.add_attachment(    
    '<p>hello world</p>',    
    subtype='html',    
    filename='instrusion.html',    
    headers=['Content-Description:This is an attachment'],    
)    
    
print(msg.as_string())
```

Produces this output:

```
Subject: This message has an attachment
From: me@example.com
To: you@example.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============1754799949587534235=="

--===============1754799949587534235==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Description: This is an attachment
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="instrusion.html"
MIME-Version: 1.0

<p>hello world</p>

--===============1754799949587534235==--
```